# Detecting route not matching uri

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-routing

I am new to Backbone and learning how to use routes.  I am trying to figure out when the expected route is missed and the router takes the default route instead.

For example...

If this is my route...

```
router.register('profile/edit/:id', 'profileView', 'views/profile');
```

and the uri is..

```
"mysite.com/index.html#profile/edit/"
```

The above route wouldn't be used and would instead go to the default route.  I could setup a route without the id to catch that but I am not sure if that is best practice.  Also, I don't want to clutter up my route registration for a bunch of routes without ids.

Would it be better to setup routes without the id or to detect that the default route was used?  If I went down the road of detecting that the default was used but there was some form of uri what would be the best way to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use default routes like:

```
router.register('profile/edit/*other', ...);
```

with splat part (as in Backbone docs: http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes)

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for.  Thanks.